# extjs file upload invalid JSON response

Tags: php, extjs

I am attempting to upload a file to PHP from extjs.  The file is uploading properly but the UI gets stuck and throws the following error: Uncaught You're trying to decode and invalid JSON String:

I have searched and found suggestions to set the Content-type header to text/html but that didn't work.  Here is my code:

```
xtype:'form',
width:300,
bodyPadding:5,
frame:false,
items: [{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    name: 'csv',
    msgTarget: 'side',
    allowBlank: false,
    buttonOnly:true,
    anchor: '100%',
    buttonText: 'Import CSV',
    listeners: {
        'change': function(fb,v){
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            form.submit({
                url:'/Portal/parsecsv.php',
                standardSubmit:false,
                method:'PUT'
            })
        }
    }
}]
```

In parsecsv.php, I simply have:

```
<?php header('Content-type:text/html');?>
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved.  The issue was that on a file upload, ExtJS by default expects a JSON response, but for some reason, ExtJS wraps the JSON response inside  tags.  So what I had to do is set the content-type of the response to text/html in PHP and then in ExtJS, parse the response as a String, not JSON.  Also, I found that on a successful upload, ExtJS fires the "failure" event instead of the "success" event upon form submission.

Comment: Sure that adding tags was ExtJS and not the Browser?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an invalid Json string. I leave the problems at the very start out because you might just not have added the full Json string to your question and I only highlight inside what you've pasted:

```
'change': function(fb,v){
```

This is not valid Json. Remove the javascript from the response in your work towards a valid Json string.

Answer (score 1):

Correct header for JSON is

```
Content-type: application/json
```